# Get value from array of objects as RxJS observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs

I have an array of objects `myData$` which is an `BevahiorSubject` (from the RxJS library). `myData$` looks like this:

```
[
  {
    type: 'car',
    year: 12,
  },
  {
    type: 'boat',
    year: 9,
  },
]
```

I want to assign the value from the `year`-key of the object that contains the string-value `'car'` at the `type`-key to my other Observable `desiredYear$`, but it should directly get the value without being stored in an array. So `desiredYear$` should equal `12`, not `[12]`.

First step, I tried getting the right object by filtering for `'car'`-string:

```
this.desiredYear$ = this.myData$.pipe(
  map(
    myData => myData.filter(data => data.type === 'car'),
  ),
);
```

It returns the object of the desired value but not yet the desired value of `year`-key, and the result (see below) is stored in an array (which I don't want):

```
[
    {
        type: 'car',
        year: 12,
    },
]
```

What can I do go get directly `12` returned?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say better fit is to use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and access the `year` property directly

```js
this.desiredYear$ = this.myData$.pipe(
  map(
    myData => myData.find(data => data.type === 'car')?.year,
  ),
);
```

The [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator would mitigate errors if the `Array#find` returns `undefined`. Which it would if there is no element in array satisfying the condition `data.type === 'car'`.

Note that in such a case, the `desiredYear$` observable would emit `undefined`. If you wish to ignore the `undefined` emissions, you could pipe in `filter` operator

```js
this.desiredYear$ = this.myData$.pipe(
  map(
    myData => myData.find(data => data.type === 'car')?.year,
  ),
  filter(year => !!year)
);
```